# Reference to a static 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have some 2D arrays of a static size:

```
double quickStats[NUM_REPETITIONS][NUM_TRIALS];
double mergeStats[NUM_REPETITIONS][NUM_TRIALS];
double bstStats[NUM_REPETITIONS][NUM_TRIALS];
```

Later, I want a reference to one of them:

```
double stats[NUM_REPETITIONS][NUM_TRIALS];

    if(i == 0) {
        stats = quickStats;
    }
    else if(i == 1) {
        stats = mergeStats;
    }
    else if(i == 2) {
        stats = bstStats;
    }
```

However, this does not work.

What can I do to do what I am trying to do without nested for loops to manually copy each element into the reference array?

I just need to read from stats, it is to avoid redundant code.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C pointer to two dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808908/c-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: I am assuming you do not want an independent copy?

Comment: I am assuming you want a pointer not reference? References have to be initialized upon declaration so you cannot assign it later on. Your best bet is using a pointer or declare the reference inside the if branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#define NUM_REPETITIONS 10
#define NUM_TRIALS 10
double quickStats[NUM_REPETITIONS][NUM_TRIALS];
double mergeStats[NUM_REPETITIONS][NUM_TRIALS];
double bstStats[NUM_REPETITIONS][NUM_TRIALS];

int main(){
    double (* ptr)[NUM_TRIALS] =quickStats;
}
```

Comment: Explaining a bit more for OP; with this syntax you would then access elements via `ptr[3][4]`.   You can also point to lists of different numbers of repetitions, although the number of trials must remain fixed.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Thanks for the edit and the comment. I was using Vim's autocomplete and did not pay enough attention. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a pointer to it like this:

```c++
double (*stats)[NUM_REPETITIONS][NUM_TRIALS];
```

Since your dimensions are known at compile time you can use [**`std::array<>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which is more versatile and readable:

```c++
std::array<std::array<double, NUM_TRIALS>, NUM_REPETITIONS> stat;
```

Comment: That reference should be assigned to *something*, right ? Given the OP's question an only-slightly-wicked stack of ternary expressions would work.

Answer (score 0):

References have to be initialized upon declaration so you cannot assign it later on. Your best bet is using a pointer or declare the reference inside the if branches.

```
constexpr unsigned int N = 100;

double a[N][N] = {0};

/* Pointer. In your case, N should be NUM_TRAILS here */
double (*a_ptr)[N] = a;


/* Specified Reference Type */
double (&a_ref)[N][N] = a;

/* C++11 Auto Reference */
auto &a_autoref = a;
```

Test here: [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44ee8cd094974e6e)