# Creating arrays and accessing them with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In the C language, In my file Lire.h, I have:

```
int* D;
```

And in the file Lire.c, I have:

```
  D=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*col);
  D=(int*)CopieD;

  for(i=0; i<lig;i++){
      for(j=0; j<col;j++){
         printf("%d ",*(D+i*col+j));
       }
      printf("\n");
  }
```

This shows me:

```
      1 1 1 3 4 1 
      1 2 3 8 2 1 
      1 3 3 5 4 7 
      2 1 4 1 1 4 
      2 2 2 3 9 3 
      2 3 9 1 2 2 
      3 1 8 6 3 5 
      3 2 4 5 8 1
```

but its not working well when I put the display blocks in the file main.c

```
int main(){
for(i=0; i<lig;i++){
    for(j=0; j<col;j++){
        printf("%d ",*(D+i*col+j));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

it gives:

```
      1 1 1 3 855638020 1 
      1 2 4206857 1 1 0 
      2345187 0 1 0 4 7 
      2 1 4 1 1 4 
      2 2 2 3 9 3 
      2 3 9 1 -2146121937 1 
      3 1 -2146122209 1 1 5 
      3 0 0 0 0 0
```

????????

Comment: `pointer-to-an-array` and `pointer-to-pointer` are not _exactly_ the same thing, you know?

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends. C is not C++!

Comment: you mean the first one is a pointer-to-an-array and the second is a pointer-to-pointer ?

Comment: 2D arrays are different from "array of pointers (to array)".

Comment: "malloc" also allocates memory in bytes - so you need to adjust the amount of memory to cater for the size of the 'int'

Comment: I strongly recommend to read a C book. All your issues should be treated there.

Comment: There are plenty of 'introduction to C and pointers' websites out there. Google is a good start.

Comment: [This can help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808908/c-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: A pointer to an NxM array is usually declared as `T (*p)[M]` (for some type `T`).  Allocating memory for such an array can be done with `p = malloc( sizeof *p * N );`.

Comment: ok, i did this:
In my file Lire.h: int* D;
and in the file Lire.c
          D=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*col);
   D=(int*)CopieD;
   for(i=0; i<lig;i++){
    for(j=0; j<col;j++){
     printf("%d ",*(D+i*col+j));
    }
    printf("\n");
   }
and it's work 
but its not working well when I put the display blocks in the file main.c !!!!!

Comment: @Quentin: it is done

Comment: How do all the variables make it to `main()`'s scope ? It would be better if you could reproduce the problem in a self-contained, compilable snippet so we can actually test, or if it's not possible make sure that we have enough information to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing:

```
D=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*col); 
D=(int*)CopieD;
```

You call `malloc` to allocate some memory and assign the pointer to `D`.  You then immediately *overwrite* that pointer with the address of CopieD, thus losing your reference to that dynamically allocated memory.

Do you want `D` to simply *point* to `CopieD`, or do you want `D` to be a *copy* of `CopieD`?

If you simply want `D` to *point* to `CopieD`, then do the following:

```
int (*D)[col] = CopieD; // assumes int CopieD[lig][col]
```

`int (*D)[col]` declares `D` as a *pointer* to a `col`-element array of `int`; it is not an array, despite the presence of `[col]` in the declaration.  The expression `CopieD` "decays" from type "`lig`-element array of `col`-element array of `int`" to type "pointer to `col`-element array of `int`".

If you want `D` to be a *copy* of `CopieD`, then you would do:

```
int (*D)[col] = malloc( sizeof *D * lig ); // notice no cast, sizeof operand 
memcpy( CopieD, D, sizeof *D * lig );
```

In either case, your display code would be written as

```
for(i=0; i<lig;i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<col;j++){
        printf("%d ", D[i][j] );
}
printf("\n");
```

The subscript operator `[]` works just the same on pointers as it does on array objects.

A note on the `malloc` call:

As of the 1989 standard<sup>1</sup>, you do not need to cast the return value of `malloc`<sup>2</sup>, and under C89/90 compilers it can potentially mask a bug.  Recommended practice in C is to *not* cast the result of `malloc`.

Instead of passing a type to `sizeof`, we pass the *expression* `*D`, which will have type `int [cols]`.  So `sizeof *D` is the same as `sizeof (int [cols])`; multplying that result by `lig` gives us the total size of the array in bytes.

---

<sup>1. Prior to the 1989 standard, `malloc` returned a value of type `char *`, so a cast was required if you wanted to assign it to a different pointer type.  Values of type `void *` can be assigned to other pointer types (and vice versa) without an explicit cast.  


2. In C, anyway; C++ requires the cast, but you shouldn't use `malloc` in C++ code.</sup>